# Get city place-id when looking for an address on Google Places Autocomplete

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I'm trying to get the **Place-id** from a city or region when looking for an address throught an autocomplete input box. The issue is that when I look for any address I can get the City Name and some others details (JSON format), but...

is there any way to get the **place-id** of that address city (or village) directly from that first query? 
and if not, what is the most efficient way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How exactly are you using Google Places API Autocomplete?  It sounds like maybe you're using `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete)?

Comment: Well, currently I'm just using the url **https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=xxxxxxxxxx&types=geocode&key=mykey** to get the data, but my following idea is to migrate to the javascript embedded api, something like this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: The JSON API returns Place IDs directly, e.g. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=paris&types=geocode&key=... so I'm not sure what you're asking.  But the Javascript library is a good option too.

Comment: What I want is to get the Place_ID of the city asking for a full address. I'suppose that the Place_id returned on the address search corresponds to that address location, and not to the city in what this address is located.

Comment: Oh I see.  I didn't see that although you are autocompleting a full address, you're asking how to find the Place ID of the city in that address.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no direct way to get the Place ID of a city from the Autocompletion for an address in that city.

I suggest something like this:

1. Get the autocomplete result, which gives a Place ID for a specific place.
2. Fetch the details for that specific place, which gives a set of address components
3. Do a search for the city (or other address component you want) using the name and location from 2.

E.g.:

1. Autocomplete `empire state build` the result has a Place ID of `ChIJtcaxrqlZwokRfwmmibzPsTU`.
2. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJtcaxrqlZwokRfwmmibzPsTU&key=...` gives a location of 40.7484404,-73.9856554 and address components like:

   ```
   {
      "long_name" : "Midtown",
      "short_name" : "Midtown",
      "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
   },
   {
      "long_name" : "Manhattan",
      "short_name" : "Manhattan",
      "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
   },
   {
      "long_name" : "New York",
      "short_name" : "New York",
      "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
   },
   ```
3. A search for New York with the location and type information (`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?keyword=New+York&location=40.7484404,-73.9856554&radius=5000&types=locality&key=...`) gives a Place ID of `ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g`.

You could possibly replace step 3 with a Place Autocomplete query with `types=(cities)` (i.e. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=New+York&location=40.7484404,-73.9856554&types=(cities)`) if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.

Comment: @Oscar have you found a solution? Or anything to share about this subject?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found the best solution yet.

Comment: i cant believe google needs to be convinced to add this "feature". this is so basic.